# How do I get changes to save when selecting with a non-EF DTO type?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, devexpress

I'm using the following code to populate a DevExpress XtraGrid with data from a DB first model. Calling `SaveChanges` has no effect, and I assume this is because there are no cached objects that match the objects I select for the grid.

Is there any way I can tell EF to use the PK, `Id`, to apply new values to cached objects during saved changes? Calling `SaveChanges` works if I use the whole Employee object for the grid.

```
private void EmployeeFormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    empsGridView.OptionsBehavior.Editable = true;
    var emps = context.Employees.Select(emp => new EmployeeDescriptor
    {
        Id = emp.Id,
        FirstName = emp.FullNames,
        LastName = emp.Surname
    });

    employeeDescriptorBindingSource.DataSource = emps.ToList();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    employeeDescriptorBindingSource.EndEdit();
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous types are Immutable in C#. In VB, you can make them mutable using the "Key" keyword, although I'm not sure if EF honors that for updates. If you want your model to be editable, change the conceptual model to only include the fields you need and ensure that the unused table columns are all nullable.

Comment: I am so sorry, and embarrassed. That post was competing with my supper for attention in a very short break.I have amended the title and added the code I was referring to. The anonymous type reference was to a previous direction I took trying to solve this.

Comment: In the case of a DTO, you need to apply the changes (manually or via AutoMapper) back to the entity object on submit prior to calling SaveChanges. The context knows nothing of the DTO itself.

Comment: Thanks @Jim, now working on how to get AutoMapper to do the whole list for me, to instantiated objects. Interesting little challenge.

Comment: That's the fun part. When you add another layer of complexity, now you have two problems ;-)